# What is the best way to create json/xml response web service using java

Tags: java, android, webservice-client

What is the best way to create json/xml response web service using java

Comment: The question, as currently stated, will likely be closed because it is too broad and you showed no effort to solve the problem yourself. I suggest reading the SO FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to undertsand how to ask good questions. I also suggest searching (Google or SO) for "Java Web Service", "Java JSON/XML", etc. You will get lots of results, most with examples. Once you have tried something, and you encounter a specific problem with your approach, that would be a good time to ask a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at REST. You can easily create JSON/XML responses. Here is the reference implementation http://jersey.java.net

Answer (score 0):

[RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/) and Jetty work well together.